# Form still submitting with return false

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want it so that if people click on the send button then the form's submission should be stopped.

My aim is to submit the message but keep the user on the same page.

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kontakt").submit(function () {
        return false;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<form id="kontakt" method="post" action="send.php">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="von" id="von" placeholder="name" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="email" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="betreff" id="betreff " placeholder="betreff" />
    <br>
    <textarea style="width:500px;height:400px;" id="nachricht" name="nachricht"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="senden"></input>
</form>
<div id? "response"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gF6wg/

The problem is that if you click on 'Send', the form is still being submitted.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close your ready function. Correct JS should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kontakt").submit(function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can check Javascript errors using Mozilla Firefox **error console** (you can show it in Firefox by pressing hotkey **ctrl+shift+J**)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `)};`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kontakt").submit(function () {
        return false;
    });
)}; // <-- this
```

You should also change this:

```
<div id="response"></div>
       ^ '=' instead of '?'
```

It's definitely working, try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/gF6wg/3/

**Update:** here's the full page, just copy this into your html file: http://pastebin.com/CRzKgVhk

Here's some simple code you could use to submit the form using ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#kontakt").submit(function () {
        var empty = $(this).find("input[type=text], textarea").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
        }).length;
        alert(empty);
        if (empty !== 0) {
            $("#response").html("Bitte alles schreiben");
        } else {
            $.post("send.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a demo of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mrNHy/1/

Comment: i tried it whith that what u post but its still not workin.

sorry because of the id="response. was a mistake. changed it

if im clicking on send he will show me the php script

Comment: @user2755825 - have you tried my code yet? It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/CFqjW/4/)**

Try this

```
<form id="kontakt" method="post" action="send.php">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="von" id="von" placeholder="name" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="email" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="betreff" id="betreff " placeholder="betreff" />
    <br>
    <textarea style="width:500px;height:400px;" id="nachricht" name="nachricht"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="senden"></input> <!--change type from 'submit' to 'button'-->
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

### code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'send.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#kontakt').serialize(),
        success : function(response)
        {

        $("#response").html(response);
        } 
    }); 
});

});
```

on your send.php add this

```
<?php
  $data=$_POST['serialize'];
   $name=$data['von']; // acceess the data like this
   // do your code


?>
```

Comment: May I know why a down vote

Comment: its not working http://jsfiddle.net/CFqjW/2/

Comment: @user2755825 its works ok, I think you have to learn the basics

Comment: @user2755825 I have updated with a working fiddle check this http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/CFqjW/4/, this will not return any value,since it is a demo url

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
<script>
$("#kontakt").submit(function(event) {
 if(!event.cancelable){
  event.cancelable=true;
 }
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this),
      von = $form.find( 'input[name="von"]' ).val(),
      mail = $form.find( 'input[name="mail"]' ).val(),
      betref = $form.find( 'input[name="betref"]' ).val(),
      url = $form.attr('action');

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { von: von, mail: mail, betref: betref } );

  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
  });
});
</script>
```